# How to create 3 regex groups with the first and last group being a date

Tags: java, date, regex-group

I'm trying to create 3 regex groups using the Java Matcher.
The format of the lines I'm trying to match are as follows:

> dd/MM/yyyy some random line here dd/MM/yyyy

I need each date and the middle part in a separate group. However to get the second date separated from the middle part you need to somehow forward reference another regex group which does not seem to be supported.
I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
^([1-9]|[0-3][0-9])\.([01][012]|[1-9]|0[1-9])\.([12]\d{3}|\d{2})(.*)([1-9]|[0-3][0-9])\.([01][012]|[1-9]|0[1-9])\.([12]\d{3}|\d{2})$
```

Unfortunately this only gets me 2 groups, the first date and the remainder.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `String::split` for SPACE and take first and last elements?  Then parse with `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`. Skip regex altogether.

Comment: There's a reason regex exists and I choose it for a reason. So I'm really only interested in a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(.*)(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})$
```

Using online [tool](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) you can check that

```
11/11/1111 some random line here 11/12/2345
```

produces:

```
0: [0,43] 11/11/1111 some random line here 11/12/2345
1: [0,10] 11/11/1111
2: [10,33] some random line here 
3: [33,43] 11/12/2345
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a good start and I had already come this far, but I would like it to be a bit more advanced. Like also accept days and months in single digits, e.g. [1-9]|[0-3][0-9])\/([01][012]|[1-9]|0[1-9])\/([12]\d{3}|\d{2}